# Prevent Ajax from catching Link from a php header

Tags: php, ajax

I'am using ajax to receive result from validating Username and password from another PHP script, in that script i'am using `header("location:....");` to redirect to the admin page, but ajax catch the link and showing it in the main Login form. Any ideas :).

Comment: I don't get the question. So, you don't want the form to showing the link? And the user to knowing the link too?

Comment: no, i send username and password using ajax to a php file. in the file if username and password are validate. the script redirect you to  admin page.

Comment: when the username and password are validate, the script redirect you using header(); but the ajax catch the link and show it in the login form.

Comment: You can create a response in php, then retrieve its response with ajax, and do redirection in ajax success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

```
<?php
...
...

if ( $username && $password )
{
  $data['response'] = 'valid';
else
{
  $data['response'] = 'invalid';
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: {username : username, password: password},
    success: function(response){
             if(response.response === valid){
                window.location.replace('admin-page');
             }else{
                //error
             }
      } 
});
```